# search for strings in python

Tags: python, search

How could I search for a string in a text and add another string after it like the following:

I want to search for example "John 3 2 G" in a text if it is there I want to add strings after it

`I met John 3 2 G yesterday and..`

after run the program

`I met John 3 2 G and his brother yesterday and..`

to be known that the numbers are not fixed, they are numbers but could be changed

I used `re.sub` but in this case when the numbers are changing how could I do it ?

My attempt:

```
re.sub("John","John and his brother",text)
```

Comment: *I used re.sub*; you should show your attempts

Comment: What exactly are you planning to search for in the string? Does the name always be "John"? Will the next bit always be "digit digit capitalletter"?

Comment: yes John will be the same but how could I add a string after John N N capital ???

Comment: You should change your regex to actually include two digits and a capital letter, rather than just the literal search for `"John"`. Start [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression pattern matching to tell Python to Match "'John', followed by a space, followed by a digit, followed by a space, followed by a digit, followed by a capital letter".

```
>>> re.sub(r"John\s(\d\s\d\s[A-Z])", r"John \1 and his brother", a)
'I met John 3 2 G and his brother yesterday'
```

`\s` = whitespace

`\d` = digit

`[A-Z]` = Captial letter between A and Z.

The parenthesis around `\d\s\d\s[A-Z]` tells Python to "capture" that part of the matched pattern, allowing us to access it in the replacement string using `\1`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that they'll be numbers but you don't know for sure what the numbers will be, you could use

```
text = re.sub(r'(\w+ \d+ \d+ \w+)',r'\1 and his brother',text)
```

That should replace `"I met <word> <number> <number> <word> yesterday and..."` where John and G can be anything so long as they appear in that order with two numbers between.

If you need it to replace specifically a single capital letter in the fourth spot, you can change the `\w+` to `[A-Z]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex which uses positive lookahead,

```
>>> import re
>>> str = 'I met John 3 2 G yesterday and..'
>>> m = re.sub(r'(John.*)(?=yesterday)', r'\1and his brother ', str)
>>> m
'I met John 3 2 G and his brother yesterday and..'
```

**Explanation:**

- `(John.*)(?=yesterday)` Matches all the characters which are followed by the string John(including John) upto the string yesterday and stored it into a group.
- In the replacement part we again call the stored group through backreference.

Comment: Use of a lookahead is a better way to go. Remaining answers would fail in some occurrences.