# how to manage spaces in python

Tags: python, spaces

I wrote this code but I have a problem in representing spaces, I used format here but it didn't work as there is re.sub

```
f = "John 2 4 W bought a new car yesterday and  I'm to trying it now "
stuff = re.sub(r"John\s(\d\s\d\s[A-Z])",r"John \1     and Peter        London",f)
```

how could I manage the spaces problem using python characteristics instead printing them literary. the first on between "\1" and "and" 5 spaces, the second is between "Peter" and "London" 8 spaces

Comment: for regex `\s+` matches 1 or more whitespace characters

Comment: What are these weird string substitution challenges you [keep being given](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24392346/3001761)? Shouldn't you be doing your own homework?